# Boost Serialization of vector<char>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

Does serializing a binary sequence stored in vector cost much? For example if I am using binary archive. Will the boost::serialization library put characters to differentiate char elements of vector and make the output larger?

Answer (score 0):

**Measure it!**

The sort answers:

- No it doesn't cost much. Profile it (and see whether it fits your application)
- No, vector elements will not be differentiated for vectors of POD types. 
  <sub>(Things change when you serialize vectors containing pointers to polymorphic classes. This is obvious, since it couldn't be done more efficiently unless you have extra knowledge about the particular dataset)</sub>

---

The storage cost:

Longer answers:

- [Boost C++ Serialization overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459726/boost-c-serialization-overhead/22464553#22464553) (comparative storage efficiency of different archives, with and without compression)
- [Boost Serialization Binary Archive giving incorrect output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556145/boost-serialization-binary-archive-giving-incorrect-output/26568212#26568212) (on why some types take more than the potential bare minimum, e.g. on 64bit systems)
- Tune things

  - `boost::archive::no_header`

The runtime cost:

- [how to do performance test using the boost library for a custom library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571355/how-to-do-performance-test-using-the-boost-library-for-a-custom-library/23572674#23572674)
- Tune things

  - `boost::archive::no_codecvt`